# Modify shapes using javascript in HTML Canvas

Tags: html5-canvas

I have started learning CANVAS. After i started drawing some basic shapes, i wanted to make some modifications to them. For example, I am confused of how to modify length and width of rectangle. Should i have to clear the canvas and redraw or can i capture the object of that rectangle like the objects in java script.

Answer (score 0):

The canvas is a [raster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_graphics) graphics surface. modifying length and width of a rectangle is a [vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics) action. It is possible to scale a raster, but losses in quality can/will occur.  You can use vector graphics in the form of [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics).  But if it is only a rectangle, use a div with a border overlay-ed on your canvas.